# How to access array of objects sent via HtmlService template?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to learn to Apps Script.  On a page, I want to be able to select a radio button to choose a language and then it will play the audio file of the selected language -the files are in drive folders by language.  There are about 150 phrases on each page in 10 languages.  I got it to work with google.script.run, but it fails because it runs the script too many times.  So I thought it would be a good idea to pass them as an array of objects via HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile.

I used this in the .gs file - think it worked.

```
function doGet(){
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  tmp.audioUrls = getDownloadUrls()
  return tmp.evaluate()
}
```

The array audioUrls looks like this [{name: "blah", language: "blah", url: "https..."}....]

I am using the following script in my html file to assign the url as the audio src:

```
function loadAudio(){
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for (var i = 0, l = audios.length; i<l; i++){
    var myId = a[i].id;
    var qText = a[i].title;
    var lang = language = document.querySelector('input[name="language"]:checked').value;

    var result = audioUrls.find(file => file.name === qText +".m4a" && file.language ===    lang);

    document.getElementById(myId).setAttribute('src', result.url);
    }
}
```

The error I get says that audioUrls.find is undefined - this is the array that I included in the HtmlService template.  Could someone point me the right direction to figure out how to access the objects in that array?  Much appreciated!  As I'm learning, I'm sure there are lots of things wrong, but I am able to understand it at this level.  The simpler the better.  Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to use the object retrieved from `getDownloadUrls()` of Google Apps Script to HTML template.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification point:

- In this case, in order to use `audioUrls` at HTML, it sets the value retrieved from `getDownloadUrls()` as the string, and the string is parsed as the object at HTML side.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function doGet(){
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  tmp.audioUrls = JSON.stringify(getDownloadUrls());  // Modified
  return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```
function loadAudio(){
  const audioUrls = JSON.parse(<?= audioUrls ?>);  // Added

  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for (var i = 0, l = audios.length; i<l; i++){
    var myId = a[i].id;
    var qText = a[i].title;
    var lang = language = document.querySelector('input[name="language"]:checked').value;

    var result = audioUrls.find(file => file.name === qText +".m4a" && file.language ===    lang);

    document.getElementById(myId).setAttribute('src', result.url);
  }
}
```

### Note:

- **In your case, when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.